# How should I install WiFi driver

Tags: wifi-configuration, hp-pavilion

I was having installed and working WiFi driver on **Windows 10**, recently I came to **Windows 8.1**, but unfortunately, WiFi driver isn't working on Windows 8.1. I have tried to update WiFi adapter from **Devices Manager**, but not worked.
What should I do?

**Note**: I'm having **HP Pavilion Notebook**

Comment: You need to download appropriate drivers from the constructor's website then install them. Which Pavilion model do you have?

Comment: This is my PC info, [link](https://ufile.io/o1jhw)

Comment: The informations displayed there are not the one required! I need the model number printed below the notebook

Comment: Their is nothing written below the Laptop

Comment: Open Windows command prompt as Admin then type the command: WMIC CSPRODUCT GET NAME, then press enter. Your computer's model number will then appear below.

Comment: This is what I got from that Code:  http://prntscr.com/fge3v4

Comment: Visit the following link and download the drivers for your system: https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-pavilion-g6-2300-notebook-pc-series/5330578/model/5358786

Comment: **Check This**:- http://prntscr.com/fgebhc

Comment: Dis you download the drivers from the link I gave you? Choose an Operating system and the OS version.

Comment: Contact me: http://h4x3r.esy.es/

Comment: What's going on?! I gave you the link from where you can download almost any drivers for your computer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59963/discussion-between-ansari-abdullah-and-esqmo).